# Can I reference a random function's values with a list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of different characters, three of which are randomly chosen each time I run the program. If my functions look like this (with each string in the list referencing to these functions)

```
public void Character1()
{ agility = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3); }
public void Character2()
{ agility = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3); }
public void Character3()
{ agility = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3); }
```

and I need to add together each character's agility value, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: A string list? not a function list?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few ways, firstly you can use return types - instead of `void` you can set a method to have a type to return like `int`

Assuming you are setting an int called agility every time, you could store each value individually.

```
public int agility1;
public int agility2;
public int agility3;

public int Character()
{ return UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3); }
```

You can then call this method three times instead.

```
agility1 = Character();
agility2 = Character();
agility3 = Character();

int totalAgil = agility1 + agility2 + agility3;
```

Alternatively you could use a ref variable in your method

```
public void Character(ref int agil)
{ agil = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3); }
```

This would be used like so

```
Character(ref agility1);
Character(ref agility2);
Character(ref agility3);

int totalAgil = agility1 + agility2 + agility3;
```

Finally you could also use on variable, which is accessed by each method, which seems to be how you're trying to do it

```
public int agility = 0;

public void Character()
{ agility += UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3); }

//after three calls agility will be between 3 and 9
```

As a final note, you should probably look into how methods are used, you have three identical methods, which do not differ in code aside from their names - this defeats the object of having a method. You could have `public void Character()` and then call it three times instead of having three methods and calling them each individually.

Comment: these are all good answers but i dont think it will work for what i need, im sorry about that im still new to this so im pretty bad at explaining. the thing is i have ten characters in total and each of them must have randomized stats (agility being the one im working with right now). after they all have their stats randomized i need to randomly select three of the characters then add their agility together. my main issue is that i cant rely on the same three characters being picked every time so im not sure how to set everything up.